# Clearing node_modules in a preinstall script breaks npm install

Tags: npm, npm-install, npm-scripts

I am confused about the behavior of the npm `preinstall` hook.

In my `package.json`, I added a preinstall script:

```json
"preinstall": "./scripts/preinstall.sh"
```

And here's **preinstall.sh**:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

# Exit if any command fails.
set -e

# Set the script directory.
SCRIPT_DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" &> /dev/null && pwd )"
# Change to the script directory so that relative paths work.
cd "$SCRIPT_DIR" || exit
# Script needs to be executed from repo root.
cd ../ || exit

# Install CKEditor.
# Node modules should be removed to ensure we are working with fresh code.
cd ckeditor5 || exit; rm -rf node_modules; npm install; npm run build
cd ../

# Delete the old modules because sometimes the version will not be updated correctly.
rm -rf node_modules

# npm install will now be run after preinstall hook is complete.
```

So I run `npm install`... and `node_modules` is deleted, but then the packages are not installed.

**What I expected to happen**

1. My `preinstall` script is called, which deletes `node_modules`.
2. `npm install` occurs, installing the packages in `package.lock`.

**What actually appears to be happening**

1. `npm install` occurs, installing the packages in `package.lock`.
2. My `preinstall` script is called, which deletes `node_modules`.

This behavior doesn't make sense based on the name "`preinstall`".  So I assume I am doing something wrong.

I want to delete `node_modules` before installing, as I have had some weird issues where macOS does not properly install packages unless `node_modules` is cleared (Windows and linux are working fine).

How can I clear the `node_modules` directly automatically before `npm install`?